# jQuery can't affect "outside" divs

Tags: jquery

So, I want to do this simple thing:

```
$('#addform').html(donedata);
```

The div #addform is `<div>` and donedata is a variable. But it won't work and I kinda think I know why. In this case I want to affect a div that I'm actually in. So, after clicking a submitbutton, I want to change the contents of addform and replace them with the variable donedata.

For better understanding:

```
<div id="addform">
<div id="form">
<input type="text" value="blabla" />
<input type="submit id="submit" value="submit" />
</div>
<div id="result" style="visibility:hidden">
</div>
</div>
```

If I would change the first line of code (in the beginning of this post), so it wouldn't try to change #addform, but the content of #result (first it would make it visible via css-method) it works fine.

So, is the problem simply, that I can't change anything of a div that "I'm in" or is there something else I could do?

I'm not sure if what I wrote is actually understandable.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're trying to do is to replace `#addform` with the contents of `donedata`, which is presumably a string of HTML.

You can do this with the jQuery method [`replaceWith`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/). This removes the element in the selection (in this case, `#addform`) from the document and replaces it with new content (in this case `donedata`).

```
$('#addform').replaceWith(donedata);
```

Comment: Hm, it doesn't work. I'm not quite sure why. Read the documentation and it actually should work.

Comment: What "doesn't work"? What's the problem? Are there any errors?

Comment: It was a typo. Oh, oh. Works fine now. :)

Comment: can i ask another question? so, actually i reload what was there before clicking the submitbutton. now all the jquery isn't working anymore after clicking that buton. that's probably because i'm inside the "after submit click"-code. if you understand what i mean. i think i need to tell it that it should use the other code if like there never happened anything.

Comment: @brainbug That's because the event handlers are bound to the elements themselves. If you're continually going to be hiding and showing sections of a document, do it by actually hiding and showing them (`hide` and `show` would be good places to start). DOM manipulation like this is expensive and slow.

Comment: sorry, i'm really new to this. where's the difference (except of maybe speed) when i do click(hide) or click(show) instead of click(replaceWith(data))?

Comment: `hide` and `show` keep the elements in the document, but make them invisible. `replaceWith` removes the elements from the document and creates some new ones. Hiding and showing is almost always better.